# Use BQ data as a side-input for pubsub events

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Trying to-do something like the following

```
# process each element
class ShapeEvent(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        columns = args[0]
        print(type(columns), columns)
        d = json.loads(element.decode('utf-8'))
        # print(d)
        yield d


# dynamic table
def table_fn(element):
    if len(element) == 2:
        return 'sandbox.beamlab'
    else:
        return 'sandbox.beamlab_err'


# creating pipeline
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:

    # print(target_columns, type(target_columns))
    # print(type(pvalue.AsList(target_columns)), pvalue.AsList(target_columns))

    target_columns = (
                             p | 'QueryTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
        query='select column_name from sandbox.beamlab_c;',
        use_standard_sql=True) | beam.Map(lambda e: e['column_name']))

    events = p | 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUBSCRIPTION)

    shaped = events | 'Shape Event' >> beam.ParDo(ShapeEvent(), pvalue.AsList(target_columns))

    shaped | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                        table_fn,
                                        schema=None,
                                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
```

`generates the following error:

RuntimeError: Transform node AppliedPTransform(QueryTable/Read/SDFBoundedSourceReader/ParDo(SDFBoundedSourceDoFn)/ProcessKeyedElements/GroupByKey/GroupByKey, _GroupByKeyOnly) was not replaced as expected.`

Comment: That looks like the right way to do it, and a similar pipeline works for me when I tried it out.  Are there any other warnings or errors? Also, what's the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: running it on the DataflowRunner worked for me as well. I'm using python sdk 2.27.0. DirectRunner didn't work. I was told the issue was passed to the DirectRunner team.

Comment: can you try using ReadAllFromBigQuery instead of ReadFromBigQuery?